# Alphabets in Hollow Diamond

Tags: nested-for-loop

Input:
The input will be a single line containing an integer representing "N"

Output:
The output should be 2*N-1 rows containing letters as a Hollow Diamond shownvin the sample output

For example, if the given number is N=5
▪ Print the letters on 9 (2*5-1) rows. Huk

Comment: sounds like homework.   What have you tried so far?